# Ugly font rendering without smoothing

Tags: fonts

After disabling font smoothing, bold versions of fonts render very strange.

Example below (notice "keyboard_shortcuts"). Regular version of font is OK and behavior is problematic for many fonts (Lucida is just an example). Also, problem isn't specific for "Open File" dialog.

[image: keyboard_shortcuts]

Comment: It's to bee expected. Smoothing is enabled exactly for this reason.

Comment: And sincerly, what do you expect, to be more nicely? ..."Open file" text is not bold.

Comment: @FXDX Pardon me, what was your question again?

Answer (score 5):

Re-enable font smoothing to get nicer fonts.